# "Fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted in Drupal API call via Postman"

Tags: php, drupal, postman

Description:
First time working with a legacy Drupal system. We are encountering:

> "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1118208 bytes)"

when making an API call to my Drupal application using Postman. The built-in preview tool for API calls within Drupal is working correctly, but this issue only arises when making the same API call through Postman.

I have seen suggestions to try and increase the PHP memory_limit. The API call however seems to be working fine when tested with the internal preview tool?

[image]

[image]

Would greatly appreciate any insights into why this issue is occurring only with Postman and how I can resolve it.

Comment: I've run Drupal sites at 128MB before, but have run into enough memory issues in the admin area that I always go with 256MB these days, so I'd try kicking up your PHP memory limit.